# Spring cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, h2

My spring application starts up, tries to create an H2 database, then crashes with the following two errors. How can I resolve?

**First error:**

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 15 in XML document from 
class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml] is invalid; nested exception
 is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
```

Line 15 of this file is the following. Would it be possible to manually include the spring-beans-2.0.dtd? This is a valid link but perhaps a firewall is blocking it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<!--
    ...
    -->
<beans>
```

**Second error:**

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL 
grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? order by 
JOB_INSTANCE_ID desc]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 
"BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE" not found; SQL statement:
    SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? order by
 JOB_INSTANCE_ID desc [42102-199]
```

I have tried toggling spring settings like `spring.batch.initialize-schema=always` to no effect.

Comment: What version of Spring? Not 2.0 I hope.

Comment: v2.0.3  -- it may not be possible to increase the version at this time.

Comment: Just to clarify, spring boot v2.0.3 is about 1.5 years old.

Comment: @another_user10293412 just to clarify, Spring 2.0 which you're referring to in your XML(almost nobody uses XML configuration in new projects) was released in October 2006, it is 13+ years old, not sure if they still host that files, what a time to be alive!

Comment: I see what you are saying, fortunately it isn't that bad. hat xml is from the spring-jdbc dependency, version 5.0.7: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5.0.x/spring-jdbc/src/main/resources/org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml#L2

Comment: Right. You're using Spring 5, which is new and wonderful and supports things like annotation based configuration. Can you use that instead? Or at least update to XML schema style instead of the DTD style? https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-configuration.html

Comment: I don't control any of the XML. Everything is pulled in through dependencies. Are you suggesting to override the xml in the dependencies?

Comment: Can you post the relevant section of your pom, with the spring dependencies? Do you have a dependency on spring-beans?

Comment: All the spring dependencies from build.gradle:
`
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.0.3.RELEASE"
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.0.3.RELEASE"
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch'
    compile 'org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test'
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was file encoding. Running the jar with `-Dfile.encoding=ISO8859-1` resolved it. This is environment specific and potentially not relevant for everyone.